# jquery overlay: close child overlay without closing the parent

Tags: jquery, click, overlay

I have a "parent" overlay invoked from a clickable image.  The overlay itself has an image, a table of text, a close button (Close) and "links" that are  tagged elements that invoke a "child" overlay with the same formatting as the parent, including the close button (though no child "links" themselves).

Every time I click the close button on the "child" overlay, both the child and parent close even though I only want the child to close.  I assume it's because the jquery thinks the close event is for the parent and child since they have the same tag and class name.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img[rel]').overlay({
        oneInstance: false
    });

    $('a[rel]').overlay({
        oneInstance: false,
        onLoad: function () {
            $('.close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('a[rel]').overlay().close();
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to intercept the close click for the child and only close the child, but it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('a[rel]').overlay({
    oneInstance: false,
    onLoad: function () {
        $('.close').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('a[rel]').overlay().close();
        });
    }
});
```

To

```
$('a[rel]').each(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    that.overlay({
        oneInstance: false,
        onLoad: function () {
            $('.close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                that.overlay().close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```